# How to change the value of AnyMap dynamically?

Tags: anychart

I have created a map of my country **Tunisia** .
 I need to set the value of each governorate  dynamically using javascript.
The problem is that the code for manipulating the map works only once (**anychart.onDocumentReady()**) !
*please help me*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking some days i realised that i can create an update by myself.
after all an update=delete+recreate;
so if i want to change the data:
1) i delete all the map (*simply change the innerHTML of the container to""*)
2) i change the data (table of data so i can change the value of a field)
3) i recreate the map.

hope that will help anyone who want to use **AnyMap** framework dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a map, you can use its API to update the data and more other. Simple example is [here](https://playground.anychart.com/If7cLztw). Also you can learn more about working with data [here](https://docs.anychart.com/Working_with_Data/Overview).